# Solve $(4+3i)\cos(z)+(3−2i)\sin(z)=-4-i$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

Need some help to solve this equation.
$$(4+3i)\cos(z)+(3-2i)\sin(z)=-4-i$$

My idea was to put: $$z=x+iy$$

I then get on the left hand side: $$(4+3i)\cos(x+iy)+(3-2i)\sin(x+iy)$$
and then simplify until I can match real part of left hand side to real part of right hand side and same for the imaginary part. From here I tried to use the angle sum formulas for sin and cos but it seems like it just makes it more complicated.

Comment: Use $\cos(z) = \frac{e^{iz} + e^{-iz}}{2}$,  $\sin(z) = \frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}$ I found this the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment from @TeodorasPaura, we get$$(2+1.5i)(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})+(1-1.5i)(e^{iz}-e^{-iz})=-4-i$$Which we can rewrite as (through some fairly simple math manipulation)$$(3+3i)e^{-iz}+e^{iz}=-4-i\\\implies e^{iz}+4+i+(3+3i)e^{-iz}=0\\\implies e^{2iz}+(4+i)e^{iz}+3+3i=0\\\overset{\text{quadratic formula}}\gets e^{iz}=\dfrac{-4-i+\sqrt{15+8i-12-12i}}{2}\\=\dfrac{-4-i+\sqrt{3-4i}}{2}\\\implies iz=\ln((-4-i)+\sqrt{3-4i})/2)\\\implies z=i\ln(2/(-4-i+\sqrt{3-4i}))\\=2\pi n-2i\tanh^{-1}(2),n\in\mathbb Z$$since the sine and cosine functions are periodic in $2\pi n$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z$

Comment: $\pm \sqrt{3-4i} = \pm(2-i)$ which helps with the simplification.

Comment: @user317176 Ohhh so we would get $z=i\ln(2/(2-2i))=i\ln(1/(1-i))$ and then multiplying the numerator and denominator by the conjugate of $1-i$ would get $z=i\ln((1+i)/2)$, and that's what $-2i\tanh^{-1}(2)$ is equal to right? I can't remember tbh

Comment: Or $e^{iz} = -3 \implies iz = \ln 3 + (2k+1)\pi i\cdots $